# How to distinguish command sources in tclsh

Tags: tcl, tclsh

In tclsh, An executable command can come from the tcl itself(puts set), from c-code(MyProcA MyProcB), or from the linux environment(echo vim). Assuming that I've got commands that have already been executed via history, how should I distinguish between the sources of these commands?

Comment: A note: "linux commands" are only automatically found in an _interactive_ tclsh session.

Comment: Pls clarify: You are interested in finding out in an interactive tclsh from history only, right?

Comment: @mrcalvin Not really, I'm more interested in examining the logic behind it

Answer (score 0):

Direct running of `echo` is a feature of the command `unknown`. Normally, you'd need to do `exec echo`...

Apart from that, there isn't really much of a distinction between commands supplied by the Tcl implementation, commands defined by third-party extensions, and (to a lesser extent) commands defined by calling something like `proc`. They're all just commands. Some of those commands support additional introspection, e.g., *via* `info body` or `info object`, but that doesn't make them any less a command than something that's handled by compilation to Tcl's bytecode or as a piece of C code.